# Camel unzip file, process contents and zip again

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying to process a zip file that contains several (small) xml files. I need to unzip, process all files (transform some tags contents) and then get a zip again.

My idea was to use unmarshal, with a splitter and then aggregate them with a zip aggregator, something like this:

```
<route id="ZipFileProcess">
    <from uri="file:{{path.to.input.zip}}?move=.done&amp;moveFailed=.error&amp;readLock=rename"/>

    <!-- Unzip -->
    <unmarshal>
        <zipFile usingIterator="true"/>
    </unmarshal>

    <split streaming="true" parallelProcessing="false">
        <simple>${body}</simple>

        <!-- Process single file (xpath) -->
        <setProperty propertyName="FieldsToTransform">
            <xpath resultType="java.util.List">//*[local-name()='Field1']/text()|//*[local-name()='Field2']/text()</xpath>
        </setProperty>

        ....

        <!-- Aggregate to zip -->
        <aggregate strategyRef="zipAggregationStrategy" eagerCheckCompletion="true">
            <correlationExpression>
                <simple>${header.CamelFileName}</simple>
            </correlationExpression>
            <completionPredicate>
                <simple>${property.CamelSplitComplete}</simple>
            </completionPredicate>
            <to uri="file://{{path.to.output.zip}}?fileName=${header.CamelFileName}&amp;tempPrefix=TEMP_"/>
        </aggregate>

    </split>
</route>
```

But this produces the following error:

```
org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.StreamCache with value [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream] due java.util.zip.ZipException: too many length or distance symbols
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.createTypeConversionException(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:667)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:158)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:87)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultStreamCachingStrategy.cache(DefaultStreamCachingStrategy.java:191)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$StreamCachingAdvice.before(CamelInternalProcessor.java:810)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$StreamCachingAdvice.before(CamelInternalProcessor.java:789)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:149)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:715)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:638)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:248)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:122)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:452)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:219)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:183)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.util.zip.ZipException: too many length or distance symbols
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1830)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.invokeMethod(ObjectHelper.java:1409)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.StaticMethodTypeConverter.convertTo(StaticMethodTypeConverter.java:59)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:326)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:141)
        ... 31 common frames omitted Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: too many length or distance symbols
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
        at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:202)
        at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:174)
        at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copyAndCloseInput(IOHelper.java:234)
        at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copyAndCloseInput(IOHelper.java:230)
        at org.apache.camel.converter.stream.StreamCacheConverter.convertToStreamCache(StreamCacheConverter.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.invokeMethod(ObjectHelper.java:1405)
        ... 34 common frames omitted
```

I am guessing this is due to the fact that each body is a stream of the unzipped file... but, is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do without writing the files to disk when unzipping?

Memory won't be a problem as a zip contains about 10 files of 8kb each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory is not a problem an option could be to convert each split exchange body (i.e. each file content) in to a string with:

```
<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
```

as first step after the spliting.

Comment: That doesn't work... It converts the stream into a String, but I do not have access to the file contents to perform the `<xpath>`. Error: Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-feinhorn-nb-1556896657098-0-22 on ExchangeId: org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value ?... [Body clipped after 1 chars, total length is 14378] due org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: This actually worked. The error above was the because of the encoding of the files in the zip.